# Is it ok to save order ID on clients' side as cookie?

Tags: php, cookies, woocommerce

Can someone abuse this order id to hack someone's detail? I am saving this for a notification feature. I just want to identify unique order made by customers. I've figured out order ID is the most unique data that I can think of. Please let me know if there's any security issue with this.

Comment: What about using `SESSION`s? Then the client only has an identifier to a record on the server.

Comment: I'd prefer cookies. Session is not accurate and cookie is the most precise way to determine unique order of customers

Comment: Just want to figure out if saving order id as cookie has any security issues

Comment: How is `SESSION` not accurate and a cookie is?

Comment: I can't use session in this case. I have angular script querying firebase according to unique value (order ID). I want to keep this simple. Cookie is straightforward solution

Comment: I think this thread is more on topic, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36318/store-username-in-cookie-for-a-web-site and/or http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123830/why-is-storing-usernames-in-cookies-bad. It is hard to say exactly if your usage is safe since we don't know how you are using. I'd prefer to go the `SESSION` route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115172/discussion-between-englishmaster-and-chris85).